# Connect to AXIS Web Service Issues

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, axis

So here's the deal.

I'm attempting to use Visual Studio to connect to an AXIS web service.  Unfortunately, the Web Service does not have a public WSDL file available on the server.  I know the location of the Web Service, but it will not let me open the WSDL file from a browser.

Luckily, I do have a local copy of the WSDL file that the server is using.  Now I know I can use SVCUTIL.EXE to build a class of the local WSDL file that can be accessed with Visual Studio.  However, I need to know how to use the generated class to run services with the server.

Normally, I can use Visual Studio's "Data Source" tool to point it to the right web address and have it take care of the hard stuff, but because the server is trying to hide the web service, how do I connect Visual Studio to the server?

Specific examples in C# would be **greatly** appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want to use WCF for your client or the 'classic' web services client stuff? When you say "Data Source" I'm assuming you're refering to the "Add Web Reference..."/"Add Service Reference..." wizard?

Comment: I'm pretty new to web services, so I'm not sure if I'd rather use WCF or the classic stuff.  And yes, I did mean the Web Service Wizard.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just host the wsdl on your local IIS... point the "Add Service Reference..." wizard at the WSDL hosted locally, then use the application's ".config" file to re-direct the service reference to the actual URL.